# Vertically centering content div inside parent div (width in %)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the content within #contactboxsplit1 (the blue div in the picture) to sit responsively vertically-centered rather then at the top of it's parent div but cannot figure out how.

Code & screenshot posted below. Thanks in advance for any help. T

```css
.contactsplitwrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  padding-bottom: 7%;
}

.contactsplitwrapper a {
  color: #000;
}

.contacttitle {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 3% 0 1% 0;
}

.contactboxsplit {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#contactboxsplitmain {
  background: #2A06E4;
}

#contactboxsplit1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #2A06E4;
}

#contactboxsplit1 img {
  width: 7%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  height: .1;
}

.contactboxhalf {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

#contactboxhalf2 {
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
}

#contactboxsplit2 {
  background: #F31115;
}

#contactboxsplit2 img {
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactsplitwrapper" id="#p7">
  <div class="contacttitle">
    <header>
      <h2> Where to find us</h2>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="contactboxsplit" id="contactboxsplitmain">
    <div id="contactboxsplit1">
      <p>
        <h3>For bookings & events please email us at <a href="mailto:info@ninelivesbar.com">info@ninelivesbar.com</a> or please call 0207 407 8226.<br></h3>
      </p>
      <div class="contactboxhalf" id="contactboxhalf1">
        <h3>
          <a href="http mapslink">
     'NINE LIVES'<br>
     BASEMENT<br>
     8 HOLYROOD STREET<br> 
     LONDON <br>
     SE1 2EL<br></p></a>
          <p>
            <img src="img/phone.png" class="phoneicon">0207 407 8226<br>
            <img src="img/mailicon.png">info@ninelivesbar.com<br>
          </p>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="contactboxhalf" id="contactboxhalf2">
        <h3>
          Opening times<br><br> Mon | Closed.. for now<br> Tue | 5pm - Midnight<br> Wed | 5pm - Midnight<br> Thu | 5pm - Late<br> Fri | 5pm - Late<br> Sat | 5pm - Late<br> Sun | Closed.. for now<br></h3>
        <!-- Left align -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contactboxsplit">
    <div id="contactboxsplit2">
      <img src="img/location.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: layout]

Comment: Hi there, just 2 tips: 1. Don't use `h3` inside a `p` tag. `h3` is a block-element and should stand for itself. 2. Use correct indentations at your CSS for better readability ;) As for your solution: Wrap the blue and red element inside a div and use `display: flex; align-items: center;` on the wrapper

Comment: @lumio Thanks for your suggestions/help. Ammended the h3/p tag, silly mistake.

I tried your solution of wrapping them inside a div with display: flex; align-items: center; but it did not work :/

Comment: See Yodas response below. That should actually work. If not, tell us :)

Comment: @ShivamArora Thanks for your extremely constructive and helpful comment. I apologise for not being pro but I am self taught and still learning. Hence why I am asking for help on forums like this.

Comment: @lumio Cannot get it to work still. The solution given is fairly simple and I am not sure I understand which div I apply the styling to to get the desired effect.

I think the width being in % rather then px maybe clashing, but I don't want the div to be a fixed px height.

Comment: You may need to restructure your html and css somewhat, the current code is quite hectic and you may have some competing css rules. My advice would be to start fresh with the smallest possible increment then build it back up from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex for this. By making the container `display: flex` and applying the property `align-items: center;`

As you can see we don't need floats or anything else really.

EDIT: For some reason the stack overflow snippet rendering is not displaying this correctly 0_p

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/300">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100">
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dz1cd13/)

Comment: Give the container a fixed height. I guess the problem is, that the code snippet renders to a default height, because the images are not loaded yet.

Comment: Okay, doesn't seem to work either :D sorry about that